# node.js async promises sequential execution

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Firebase functions using node.js

In the below code "pushNotifications" function is triggered when there is new entry in the messagesDB.

From the messagesDB i am getting the email from the messages dictionary.

1. Calling the function getUserID() with email address to fetch the UID
2. UID collected is then pass it to the getUserStatus(uid) and get the current status which returns a bool.

i will not be able to get the status of the user without his uid, and needed to executed sequentially.

(I can execute them individually using hardcoded values, but not sequentially)
Any help will appretiated.

```
function getUserStatus(uid) {

  var onlineStatus = true;
  console.log('getting the status.........', uid);
  return firestoreDB.collection('userstatus').doc(uid).get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        onlineStatus = doc.data()['online'];
      }
      return onlineStatus;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err;
    });
}

function getUserID(toId) {
  var uid;
  console.log('get uid function....');
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(toId)
    .then((userRecord) => {
      console.log('record :', userRecord);
      uid = userRecord.uid
      console.log('uid :', uid);
      console.log(`getting document`);
      return uid;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error fetching getUserID :", error);
      return err;
    })
}


exports.pushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/Messages/{messageID}').onWrite(event => {

  console.log('event Data : ', event.after._data);
  const data = event.after._data;
  const fromId = data.from;
  const toId = data.to;
  const message = data.messageText;
  console.log(fromId + ' sent a message to ' + toId);
  console.log('getting uid..');

  const statusOnline = getUserID(toId)
  .then(uid => {
                console.log('got uid', uid); 
                getUserStatus(uid)
              })
  .then(status => {return status})
  .catch(err => console.log('Error executing the promises', err.message));
  console.log('statusOnline : ', statusOnline);
  console.log('Done.......');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a return statement, and hence the promise down below is not receiving any output.

```
const statusOnline = getUserID(toId)
  .then(uid => {
    console.log('got uid', uid); 
    return getUserStatus(uid); // return your result
  })
  .then((status) => .... )
```

and also you are not really doing anything with your status. try `console.log(status)` after you have received the status.

```
.then(status => {
  console.log("the status obtained was ", status);
  return status
})
```

and promises don't work as you are using them. By setting the variable as a Promise you can not simply console log its output before it is done executing itself. so instead of `console.log('statusOnline : ', statusOnline);` do something like this

```
statusOnline.then(result => {console.log('statusOnline : ', result)});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to 'resolve' where you are 'return'ing and 'reject' where you catch/throwing.